# Completeness of Gamma family

Tags: mathematical-statistics, gamma-distribution, sufficient-statistics, complete-statistics

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ has a Gamma$(\alpha,\alpha)$ distribution. Find the minimal sufficient statistics. Is this a complete family?

**My attempt**: I found the Minimal sufficient statistics is $T(x)=(\sum_iX_i,\prod_i X_i)$ and I guess that this family is not complete because the parameter space has a lower dimension than the statistics space.

**My question:** I cannot rigorously state that this family is not complete just because of the lower parameter space. Any ideas on how to show that this is not a complete family? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

For clarity, I am assuming the $\alpha$ are both shape and rate parameters, i.e., the density of $X_i$s is
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \frac{\alpha^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha - 1}e^{-\alpha x}, \quad x > 0.
\end{align*}

With this density, $E[X_i] = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha} = 1$, which is independent of $\alpha$.  Therefore, for $g(x, y) = \frac{1}{n}x - y$, by the i.i.d. assumption of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$, we have
\begin{align*}
E[g(T(X))] = E\left[g\left(\sum X_i, \prod X_i\right)\right] = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^nE[X_i] - \prod_{i = 1}^nE[X_i] = 1 - 1 = 0
\end{align*}
for all $\alpha > 0$.  On the other hand, $g(x, y)$ is clearly not $0$ (more formally, there exists $\alpha > 0$, such that $P_\alpha\left(\sum X_i = n\prod X_i\right) < 1$). This shows that $T(X)$ is not complete.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the case is the (shape, scale) that is $\mathbb E[X_i]=\alpha^2$

Comment: @CynoBenette In that case I am afraid the proof would become much more difficult.  Given the answer has been posted, I suggest you make a new post and make it clear that the second $\alpha$ is a scale parameter (and in the future if the question may bear some ambiguity, do please add a few more sentences to resolve the potential ambiguity).  It would be even better if you can tell us where the original problem comes from so that people won't spend time on a problem that may not have assertive answer.